# How to convert backward slash command in python to run on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x

I get error on this line when I run code in Linux:

```
dst_file_path = "%s\%s" % (dst,loc[1])
```

How can do this using some module. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need a literal backslash in a string, escape it by putting 2 backslashes, or use a raw string. Otherwise, you'll get weird errors where a string turns out to have a backspace or a form feed in it instead of the literal `\b` or `\f` you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

[`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will automatically include the correct directory separator based on the platform being used.

```
import os

dst_file_path = os.path.join(dst, loc[1])
```

Comment: I don't think it's for a posix file path, since he's using a backslash on Linux

Comment: @khalid I can't really use os.path.join cause loc[1] isn't exactly path (its just text e.g. \new_folder\new.txt) so when I try to join path it gives error and slashes gets mixed

Comment: It doesn't matter if its a path or not, you just need to parse out the existing slashes first.

Answer (score 3):

```
dst_file_path = "%s\\%s" % (dst,loc[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

In strings, the "\" character is used to escape the standard meanings of other characters. For example, a newline character, which we type as "Enter," is seen in Python as `\n` The backslash in your code is being read as a way to escape the usual meaning of the next character. If you just want a backslash, you have to escape the meaning of the backslash character. Ironically, this is done with another backslash: `\\` To have Python read your strings as you would, which nullifies backslash benefits and string formatting things with `%`, you can put an `r` in front of your string, identifying it as a raw string.

Answer (score 0):

or alternatively

```
dst_file_path = r"%s\%s" % (dst,loc[1])
```

if you're not making a filepath for the current file system, you can use the specific underlying module of `os.path`. For backslashes windows style

```
import ntpath
dst_file_path = ntpath.join(dst, loc[1])
```